# What is the best way to implement modified bagging?

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, svm

I am trying to implement modified bagging classifier like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzEwI.jpg).
what is the best way to implement this modified classifier?Is it possible to implement this with sklearn packages?If the answer is yes how can do this?
for more details about this problem there is some [pseudocode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2Lqd.png).
I want to use grid search with this modified classifier.because of that it is better to implement this with sklearn packages.

Comment: should be possible but some manual work is needed. I'd assume you can create a handcrafted pipeline using additionally [imbalanced learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn). Not 100 percent sure, if you can split the training data in your desired way in a pipeline (with a custom transformer, maybe)

Comment: May be this can help https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#imblearn.pipeline.Pipeline

Comment: Also check this https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.ensemble.BalancedBaggingClassifier.html#imblearn.ensemble.BalancedBaggingClassifier